# String Split()-method

Tags: c#-2.0

Why am I getting this error?

```
public class ParameterParser
{
    public List<string> ParseParameter(string queryString)
    {
        queryString = queryString.Replace(" ", "");

        string[] strs = queryString.Split(@"(", @"=", @",", @"<>", 
                                          StringSplitOptions.None);

        List<string> parameters = new List<string>();

        foreach (string ss in strs)
        {
            string s = ss.Trim(')');

            if (s.StartsWith("@") && !s.Equals("") && s!=null)
            {
                parameters.Add(s.Replace(" ", ""));
            }
        }

        return parameters;
    }
}
```

Error   3   The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments   F:...\ParameterParser.cs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to pass an array of strings, you have to do that explicitly:

```
string[] strs = queryString.Split(new string[] {"(", "=", ",", "<>"}, 
                                  StringSplitOptions.None);
```

I suspect you were modelling your code on something like this:

```
string[] strs = queryString.Split('(', '=', ',');
```

This is using a *parameter array* (the `params` modifier in C#). Parameter arrays are only applicable for the final parameter, and no overload of `String.Split` takes a `params string[]`. That's why it wasn't working for you.

Note that I've changed the strings into simple string literals - I would recommend only using verbatim string literals when you actually need to.

Answer (score 0):

@"(", @"=", @",", @"<>"  is not a single string or a char[] array

Try this:

```
string[] strs = queryString.Split(new string[] {@"(", @"=",@",",@"<>" },StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx

Comment: I didn't say that it did I just said it wasn't! ;)